# Uploading .ipa to testflight via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, testflight

I am using jenkins for auto build and auto deploy. Till now I successfully achieved build generation (i.e .ipa file). I also achieved diawi link generation.

Now I want to upload .ipa to testflight via jenkins. Right now I am using this script for uplaod,

```
 ipa distribute:itunesconnect \
 —-file "${WORKSPACE}/build/upload.ipa" \
 —-account yourappleid@gmail.com \
 -p Y0urPa55w0rd \
 —-apple-id 1234567890 —-upload —-verbose
```

but jenkins gives me error given below,

```
*** Error: Unable to validate your application. Unable to read password from stdin.
```

What's wrong in this script OR any other script will be used for upload. So, please anyone can help me to upload an .ipa to testflight via jenkins.

Comment: Hello, I am currently stuck at just building the project on new commit. I don't know how to create an .ipa and upload it to test flight. Can you suggest some tutorial for this ?

Comment: You can refer this link for setting up and create .ipa.

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/step-step-tutorial-continuous-integration-jenkins-red-hat-mobile-native-ios-application-0

Comment: Thank you @Jenish.

Comment: Can you share the blog/article which you followed for generating the .ipa file?

Comment: Hey, @nr5 
For startup Jenkins, I used [this link](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/step-step-tutorial-continuous-integration-jenkins-red-hat-mobile-native-ios-application-0). This article has two parts. Given link is part-2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am done it. Successfully upload an .ipa to testflight via jenkins.

**ALTOOL** is a command line tool that helps you to upload an .ipa to testflight. You just need to go to the path of **altool** (xcode inbuilt tool) of your xcode, and then fire a command for uploading an .ipa to testflight.

Below is the script/command that you need to write in **Execute Shel**l of **Build phase**.

```
cd  /Applications/Xcode\ 8.3.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/

./altool --upload-app -f /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/yourWorkspace-name/build/artifacts/yourIPA.ipa -u itunesconnectUserName -p itunesconnectPassword
```

Comment: For this, XCode should be installed on the machine where Jenkins is installed right ? Is there a Pure jenkins way to do this?

Comment: Yes, Xcode needs to be installed because this is default command-line argument of Xcode to upload an app to test flight.

Comment: You can use `xcrun altool` and it will find where altool is installed. It's not necessarily in that path.

Comment: Can you pls specify the details of this command, it is not very helpful @Jenish